# I want to get a guide using denomongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, plugins, deno

The guide page from deno-mongo github no longer works.
You can access the page at the following address: 'https://github.com/manyuanrong/deno_mongo'

I have no understanding of the plug-in, so it's hard for me to get it started.

When I follow the example from "Readme.md",

```
import { MongoClient } from 'https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.11.1/mod.ts'

const client = new MongoClient()
client.connectWithUri('mongodb://localhost:27017') // error seems to be thrown here

const db = client.database('test')
const users = db.collection('users')

const insertId = await users.insertOne({
  username: 'user1',
  password: 'pass1'
})
```

the errors occurs like this:

```
Error: The plugin must be initialized before use
    at dispatch (util.ts:72:11)
    at MongoClient.connectWithUri (client.ts:101:18)
    at ...
```

With a follwing INFO message (maybe from the denomongo module)

```
INFO load deno plugin "deno_mongo" from local `/home/${localfiles}/.deno_plugins/deno_mongo_5c404deeadd1e8a86535eb51aca17e4d.so`
```

I struggled to solve this problem and tried the following.

```
import { init, MongoClient } from 'https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.11.1/mod.ts'

init(${pathname}) // in real code, i gave the real path where '.deno_plugins/deno_mongo~~~.so' is. (even though I don't know what is this file for, when it is created)

const client = new MongoClient()
client.connectWithUri('mongodb://localhost:27017')

const db = client.database('test')
const users = db.collection('users')

const insertId = await users.insertOne({
  username: 'user1',
  password: 'pass1'
})
```

But it only caused additional INFO message:

```
INFO downloading deno plugin "deno_mongo" from "${pathname}/libdeno_mongo.so"
```

It didn't work.

How can I handle it?

Comment: Had the same issue and I just reverted to v0.8.0 which works.

Comment: I have a small project running with deno and mongo: https://github.com/ramonmedeiros/learning_deno

Comment: It was about a bug in Deno itself. Awaiting Deno's dynamic import doesnt work. So, I initialized mongodb module at the start of main process, so that dynamic import which imports mongodb in itself can connect mongodb without additional waiting of initialization

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the code

```
init(${pathname})
```

Then try to run your app.ts with bellow command

```
deno run --allow-net --allow-write --allow-read --allow-plugin --allow-env --unstable app.ts
```

With the old version of [deno_mongo](https://github.com/manyuanrong/deno_mongo) (0.11.0 and lower), the library will automactially download the plugin that use a native command to connect to your mongo server like Mongo Atlas.